# how to make an Dictionary Extension showing a small icon or popup when dragging a word?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to create an extension that displays icons or small screens when dragging

Examples

[image]

but I don't know how to make it

I tried to find things that could be a reference in the Chrome extension store, but it failed.
Can I get any example?

Comment: There's no special API for extensions. Use the standard web approach (listen to `selectionchange` then add a DOM element with the popup) in your `content script`. See also [How to isolate stylesheets in content script](/a/25100953).